# Is there a simple proof for this?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm trying to simplify some paper, which uses the following theorem:

Let $X_n$ be random variables taking Values in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2) < \infty$ and $\forall n: E(X_n|X_1, ..., X_{n-1}) = 0$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges with probability 1.

In the paper (Blum 1954: approximation methods which converge with probability one) the author uses some far more general Lemma from another paper, but i would like to prove just this theorem so I don't have to rely on other papers for my proof.
I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y_n= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ defines  a martingale. Verify that $EY_n^{2}=EY_{n-1}^{2}+EX_n^{2}$ by conditioning  on $X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1}$ (and expanding $(X_n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} X_k)^{2}$). It follows that $EY_n^{2} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} EX_k^{2}$, so $(Y_n)$ is a $L^{2}$ bounded martingale. Hence it converges almost surely.